mvn package fails due to missing ApplicationArguments?
I developed an Java Email archiving application with Spring Boot and Maven and provide ApplicationArguments when I run it. It works all well to run it. But now I wanted to create an executable JAR from that application, but when I use mvn package I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because the return value of "org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments.getOptionValues(String)" is null" for the line "String emailBasePath = this.appArgs.getOptionValues("emailbasepath").get(0); in the following piece of code:
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class EmailstoreApplication {
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationArguments appArgs;
    
    @Autowired
    private EmailInitializer emailInit;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean("init")
    public InitializationArguments initalize() {
        String emailBasePath = this.appArgs.getOptionValues("emailbasepath").get(0);
        this.emailInit.initializeEmails(emailBasePath);
        return new InitializationArguments(emailBasePath);
    }
}

But of course I don't want to pass this when I create the JAR but I want to set it dynamically when I execute the JAR. (And I also cannot see how I would be able to set it for the creation of the JAR, because it's a application argument and not a JVM argument.)
For packaging I use spring-boot-maven-plugin with the goal "repackage".
What am I doing or thinking wrong?
